# how to handle deprecation warning in momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I want to use momentjs to check for invalid date/time strings:

```
var invalid = '2017-03-18 23;00;00';
if (moment(invalid).isValid()) {
  return 'valid date'
}
```

This (correctly) throws a stacktrace with the familiar 'Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format......'

But even if I add a try/catch:

```
try {
  var invalid = '2017-03-18 23;00;00';
  if (moment(invalid).isValid()) {
    return 'valid date'
  }
catch (err) {
  throw Error ('invalid date format');
}
```

the stacktrace is still printed.
What do I need to do to avoid the stacktrace from being printed?

I've searched all similar questions on StackOverflow but they all try to solve a different problem (fixing the input or finding the correct syntax to parse the input).

I using v2.18.1.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to use [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse your input. If you don't want to specify a format (or an [array of formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)), you can use [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/). As the docs says:

> Moment already supports parsing iso-8601 strings, but this can be specified explicitly in the format/list of formats when constructing a moment

This way you will not have deprecation warning. Here a working example:

```js
var invalid = '2017-03-18 23;00;00';
if (moment(invalid, moment.ISO_8601).isValid()) {
  console.log('valid date');
} else {
  console.log('invalid date');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

PS. Anyway, if you have a list of accepted format, I suggest to use `moment(String, String[]);` (and strict parsing, if needed).

Answer (score 4):

Specify the string format for your date then the warning will go away

```
moment("2017-1-27", 'YYYY-M-D').format('DD MMMM YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Below works for me to remove RFC2822 warnings

Use moment(String, FormatString) to convert string to date.

```
 var newDt = Moment(this.state.dob,"MM/DD/YY")
```

And below code from date to String

```
var dt = Moment(newDt).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

By this way it will not show warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.format()` without any arguments to the moment expression that was causing that warning was the solution for me:

```
moment(r.created_at.toDate()).format()
```