# Moment.js Invalid date message

Tags: javascript, datatable, momentjs

Im exploring moment.js with Datatables, and its really good for showing the date in the format that I want but there is a problem that i have with the data that I am converting.
If the date is not valid it shows the message INVALID DATE, wihch is good but not what I really want.
Is it possible to, insted of showing "Invalid Date" message, show what was in there originally?
Like if it is not a date I want to see what it is, not that message.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your help guys!
I have done this for the datatable "aoColumns":

```
{     "mData": "APE",
      "render": function(mData){
            if(mData != null){
                if(moment(mData).format("DD/MM/YYYY")== 'Invalid date')
                    {
                        return mData;                       
                    }
                else
                    {
                    return moment(mData).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    }
            }                               
                               },
        sDefaultContent: ''},
```

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: add some code and then ask for help.

Comment: actually i tried to read the moment.js file to edit it, but as I was trying to do that I was afraid because the programming of the file is complex and I did not want to explore much to not spoil anything. So I am asking to see if someone more experienced knows what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you've implemented Moment.js, you could simply check the return value from moment? For example

```
var prettyDate = moment()...;

if(prettyDate != 'Invalid date') {
    // set your date
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { invalidDate: "ur msg or NaN/null" });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var dateStr = "aw 2017-06- awd 09 10:05:21.0";
//var dateStr = "a2017-06-09 10:05:21.0";
if(moment(dateStr, moment.ISO_8601).isValid()){
  alert("Valid Date: " + moment(dateStr).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
}
else  {
  alert("Invalid Date: " +dateStr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Try creating your own function where you check if the date is valid or not, 
see [moment validation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) and if it is not valid return the original data for the message.

Update: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs) post for extra explanation on the code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)
Did not use that but it may be a good solution!
I edited my question with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Jack +1 for the good answer, but note that your snippet throws _Deprecation warining_ please use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing function to avoid it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048). (Maybe you can also update moment version to lastest one)