# Weird ISO formatted Datestring to Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've got a Datestring like this one: `20171010T022902.000Z` and I need to create Javascript Date from this string. `new Date('20171010T022902.000Z')` would return `Invalid Date`.

I saw that it's possible to use moment.js for this purpose but I am not sure how I would specify the according format for my given example. I found this example from another thread:

```
var momentDate = moment('1890-09-30T23:59:59+01:16:20', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+-HH:mm:ss');
var jsDate = momentDate.toDate();
```

**Question:**

How can I create a JavaScript date from a given Datestring in this format: `20171010T022902.000Z` (using moment)?

Comment: Well, just drop the delimiters from the format string?

Comment: Like this: `new Date(20171010T022902)` ? Results in => SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: No. That isn't using the moment.js interface at all

Comment: wow simply `moment('20171010T022902.000Z')` actually does work. I've never expected that. Do you want to write an answer for that so I can accept it?

Comment: As the example shows, you should also pass a format string (like `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+-HH:mm:ss'`) to it, customised to whatever your exact format is. Check the docs for what is available

Comment: Actually it does work without providing the format string, moment seems to recognize the format somehow.

Comment: Still, you should not count on that, afaik it also logs some warnings if you use it without an explicit format string.

Comment: @Bergi There will be no warning in this case, because `20171010T022902.000Z` matches known ISO 8601 format. If you want to pass the format parameter anyway you can use [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048) and [here](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/).

Comment: Note that the "wierd" format isn't weird at all.  ISO8601 describes several formats.  The one with the separators is called "extended".  The one without separators is called "basic".

Comment: @VincenzoC Ah, thanks, I didn't know this was a standard format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input (`20171010T022902.000Z`) matches known ISO 8601 so you can simply use [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) parsing method. In the [Supported ISO 8601 strings](http://momentjs.com/docs/#supported-iso-8601-strings) section of the docs you will find:

> ```
> 20130208T080910.123      # Short date and time up to ms
> ```

Then you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method

> To get a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps

Your code could be like the following

```js
var m = moment('20171010T022902.000Z');
console.log( m.format() );
console.log( m.toDate() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that this code does not shows Deprecation Warning (cited in Bergi's comment) because you input is in ISO 8601 known format. See [this guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/) to know more about this warning.

Moreover *"By default, moment parses and displays in local time"* as stated [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) so `format()` will show the local value for your UTC input (`20171010T022902.000Z` ends with `Z`). See [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), [`utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) and [Local vs UTC vs Offset guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) to learn more about moment UTC mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without moment.js,.

Basically extract the parts you need using regex's capture groups, and then re-arrange into a correct format for new Date to work with.

```js
var dtstr = '20171010T022902.000Z';

var dt = new Date(
  dtstr.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\.\d{3}Z)$/,
    "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6$7"));
  
console.log(dt);
console.log(dt.toString());
```

If you are using moment.js anyway, this should work ->

```js
var dt = moment("20171010T022902.000Z", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss.SSSSZ");

console.log(dt.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```