# Handle momentjs deprecation warning in Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, momentjs

Im writing unit test case for formatting date using moment.js

typescript Code:

```html
formatDate(date) {
  date ? moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY') : '';
}
```

Unit test case:

```
it('should return `Invalid date`', () => {
  const date = '20111011000000Z';

  expect(component.formatDate(date)).toBe('Invalid date');
});
```

Im getting the below warning while run this unit test, how to avoid this warning.

```
WARN: 'Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or 
ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not 
reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date forma
ts are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please 
refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, 
_i: 20111011000000Z, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object 
Object]
undefined'
```

Could you please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle deprecation warning in momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs)

Comment: Follow the URL in the deprecation message itself.  It explains what you need to do.