# Moment.js Date Returning Invalid

Tags: reactjs, date, momentjs

I have a React app that is parsing some dates using Moment.js/Timezones. I'm getting data from an API, and many dates return correct and are parsed but a few aren't. For example, this date: `2018-04-03T02:10:00Z` parses correctly where as this one does not: `2018-04-03T01:40:00Z`. I don't see any reason why this should be the case.

I am using moment.timezone to guess the users timezone:

```
this.state = {
  userZone: moment.tz.guess()
}
```

and then mapping through my API response and outputting the date (or state of the game if in progress).

```
{this.props.status === 'Scheduled' ? moment(this.props.gameDate, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM00Z').tz(this.state.userZone).format('h:MM A z') : this.props.status}
```

I'm pretty stumped as to why this is happening to only a few dates and have actually been spinning my wheels on this off and on for 4 months... Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be a big deal or not, but ISO dates should have a 3-digit millisecond before the `Z`: `2017-09-14T18:40:16.000Z`

Comment: The second `MM` in the time part is parsed as a month, so try `mm` instead (also in `format`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issue in the way you are parsing your input. Since it is in ISO 8601 compliant format you can use [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) instead of [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

You code could be like the following:

```
{this.props.status === 'Scheduled' ? moment(this.props.gameDate).tz(this.state.userZone).format('h:mm A z') : this.props.status}
```

In your question you are using `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM00Z'` as format parameter of [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), the problem is that format tokens are case sensitive: uppercase `MM` stands for month's number while lovercase `mm` stands for minutes. `2018-04-03T01:40:00Z` gives invalid date because with your code you are tring to parse `40` as month number.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048) an example on how to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse ISO 8601 compliant inputs and take a look at [`moment.utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) if you want to explicitly parse you UTC input in UTC mode.

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have mixed something up when looking at docs. `moment(this.props.gameDate).tz(this.state.userZone).format('h:mm A z')` works great.