# How can I hide moment errors in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, momentjs

I'm fairly new to both node and javascript so I apologize if this is a tired question, but the solutions I have found in my research so far have not worked for me.

I have the following function that checks if a date string (received from the user as a command line argument) is valid:

```
var checkDate = (d) => {
    if (isNaN(d) && moment(d).isValid()) {
        return moment(d);
    } else if (!isNaN(d)) {
        return moment(parseInt(d, 10));
    } else {
        console.error(`Error! ${d} is not a valid date string.`);
        process.exit(1);
    };
};
```

The issue is that if the string is **not** a valid date, `moment(d).isValid()` will throw an error.  I would like to not see this error as it really isn't of much use and I am throwing my own under the else anyway.

Is there a way I can suppress the error thrown by the `moment().isValid()` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle deprecation warning in momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2469) with `moment` that will throw a deprecation warning when the value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.

To avoid the warning, create a fallback function:

```
const moment = require('moment');

moment.createFromInputFallback = function (config) {
    config._d = new Date(NaN);
}

const checkDate = (d) => {
    if (isNaN(d) && moment(d).isValid()) {
        return moment(d);
    } else if (!isNaN(d)) {
        return moment(parseInt(d, 10));
    } else {
        console.error(`Error! ${d} is not a valid date string.`)
        process.exit(1);
    };
};
```

Or you can supress the warning directly with:

```
moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;
```