# Express Validatior - How Do I Break The Validation Chain?

Tags: express, momentjs, express-validator

I have a date field that I want to ensure is in a valid format and if so is the user over 18. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Here is one of my validators - the one that is failing:

```
body('birthday', 'Date format should be: YYYY-MM-DD')
  .isRFC3339()
  .custom(date => { 
    const over18 = moment().diff(date, 'years') >= 18;
    if(!over18) {
      return Promise.reject('You must be 18 or over!');
    }
  }),
```

Currently what happens is if the date is not a RFC3339 date the validation chain continues. This is problematic because `moment` produces an error if I pass an ill formatted date.

How do I break the chain after the call to `.isRFC3339()` so that if the date is invalid the custom validator will not run? I couldn't find anything in the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html)

Comment: I don't know enough about express and express-validator, but if you want to prevent momentjs' _Deprecation Warning_, you can use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048) (in your case something like: `moment().diff(moment(date, moment.ISO_8601), 'years')`). You can also use momentjs [strict parsing mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) and check valid dates using [`isValid()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/).

Comment: But the problem is if a user enters `thisisnotadate` instead of a date momentjs wouldn't be able to parse that and would fail anyway.

Comment: A better idea would probably be to check if the data is valid within the custom validator and return a promise rejection if invalid.

Comment: I think I missed what is the desired output for `thisisnotadate`, I was thinking at something like: `const mDate = moment(date, moment.ISO_8601, true); const over18 = moment().diff(mDate, 'years') >= 18; if(!mDate.isValid() || !over18) return Promise.reject;` (using only custom validator without `isRFC3339()`), but I'm not sure that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup that's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use momentjs [strict mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) together with [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing using `moment.ISO_8601` (or `moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE`) [special formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/).

Your code could be like the following:

```js
body('birthday', 'Date format should be: YYYY-MM-DD')
  // .isRFC3339() // no more needed
  .custom(date => {
    const mDate = moment(date, moment.ISO_8601, true);
    const over18 = moment().diff(mDate, 'years') >= 18;
    if(!mDate.isValid()) {
      return Promise.reject('Date is not YYYY-MM-DD');
    if(!over18) {
      return Promise.reject('You must be 18 or over!');
    }
  }),
```

Comment: For some reason I had to add `return true` at the end in order for it to validate. Otherwise it was returning the `Date format should be: ...` error. No idea why as the docs don't mention it.

Comment: I don't know enough about express-validator, I'm glad that you managed to make it work adding the `return true`.

Comment: Maintainer here. [It _is_ in the docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator), but I see that it  could be more prominent. PRs welcome!