# Tempusdominus datetimepicker and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I try to use https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/ in ASP.NET MVC project.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TimeEnd,
        new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm  datetimepicker-input", 
                @data_toggle = "datetimepicker",
               @data_target = "#TimeEnd",
               type="text"
        })
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#TimeEnd" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
     <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `model.TimeEnd` is string in the format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#TimeEnd').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es', 
    });
});
```

When I open page the `input` **has correct value** but it is not visible in the **datetimepicker**.

**UPDATE #1**

If I set defaultDate via the same model  like  `defaultDate: '@Model.TimeEnd'` (where it is string in the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm) then the Spanish localization **is gone** and I see English calendar! Wow.
And the following error appears

> moment-with-locales.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is
>   not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls
>   back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and
>   versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be
>   removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:  [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false,
>   _l: undefined, _i: 14.08.2018 00:00, _f: null, _strict: false, _locale: [object Object] Error
>       at Function.createFromInputFallback (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:3368)
>       at wa (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:21353)
>       at va (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:22064)
>       at Sa (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:22146)
>       at l (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js:1:209)
>       at k.i.getMoment (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:6:14261)
>       at k.i.defaultDate (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:6:19874)
>       at String. (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:6:14947)
>       at Function.each (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:360:19)
>       at k.i.options (http://localhost:62959/Scripts/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:6:14895)

Any clue how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `defaultDate` option?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` (forward slash, not dot for the separator)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke well... I assume it could be dot as well, right? And even if I use `format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',` it does not help.

Comment: Fairly sure the date separator for `es` culture is `/`, not `.`. And as a test, does it work if you hard code a date in ISO format?

Comment: The defaultDate can accept `moment` object, try give a shot for `defaultDate: moment('@Model.TimeEnd', moment.ISO_8601)` - also worth to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the probelm was around messing up the `input` and wraping `div` ids.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                @Html.Label("Finish", new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-form-label", @for = "TimeStart2" })
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                            <input id="TimeEnd" name="TimeEnd" value="@Model.TimeEnd" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
         locale: 'es'
    });
});
```