# How to format user input into the correct localized format?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, locale

I have an `<input type="text"/>` where the user can (try to) type in a date in whatever format/syntax (even in an invalid format).

I want to get the value of whatever the user typed in, pass it through a localized moment and then update the input with the correct format.

I'm trying to follow [these guidelines in order to use a local moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/)

```
// I want to use a local instance of moment
let localLocale = moment();

// I want to set the locale to be 'fr'
localLocale.locale('fr')

// I want to set the format to be 'LL'
localLocale.format('LL')

// this is what the user typed in
let userInput = '2/3/1986'

// I want to do:
let formattedUserInput = something(userInput)
```

The value of `formattedUserInput` must be `Mars 2, 1986`

I'm looking for what `something` should be. The moment docs are so confusing there is no explanation on how to do this.

If `userInput` is obviously gibberish, the `something()` should return null or throw an error or whatever I don't mind.

I tried `localLocale(userInput)` but it throws a `localLocale is not a function`

Comment: Have you tried just using `moment(userInput)`?

Comment: Even if this works, It's not clear whether `moment(userInput)` will then be using the local instance of moment I created or not. If yes, I don't see the point of doing `let localLocale = moment();` to begin with. `moment` is defined globally so..

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's going on. You do `let localLocale = moment(userInput);`, set the locale, `localLocale('fr')` then get the formatted value `let formattedUserInput = localLocale.format('LL');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The locale set is local to the moment instance you have defined. So

```
let localLocale = moment();
localLocale.locale('fr');
```

sets the local for `localLocale` to `'fr'`. So if you want to do it locally for just this input, you'd use:

```js
// this is what the user typed in
let userInput = '2/3/1986';

// Use a local instance of moment, using the user's input
let localLocale = moment(userInput, 'D/M/YYYY');

// Set the locale to be 'fr'
localLocale.locale('fr');

// Get the formatted string
let formattedUserInput = localLocale.format('LL');

console.log(formattedUserInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-VrmtNHAdGzjNsUNtWYG55xxE9xDTz4gF63x/prKXKH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: line `let localLocale = moment(userInput, 'D/M/YYYY');` assumes that I will know what format the user used when typing the date. I won't know that. Isn't moment "clever" enough to guess the format that is passed to it and either use it correctly or return smth like "can't understand the format, looks gibberish..." ?

Comment: You can run it without that, but moment will display a warning. For instance, when I (as an American) see that user input, I would say it's the third of February. There is an overload that takes an array of formats to validate against.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) to parse inputs in difefrent formats:

> If you don't know the exact format of an input string, but know it could be one of many, you can use an array of formats.

You can use [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43101278/4131048), to parse ISO 8601 inputs as [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) does.

Please note that [`moment(String, String[])`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)

> Starting in version **2.3.0**, Moment uses some simple heuristics to determine which format to use. In order:
>
> - Prefer formats resulting in [valid](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) dates over invalid ones.
> - Prefer formats that parse more of the string than less and use more of the format than less, i.e. prefer stricter parsing.
> - Prefer formats earlier in the array than later.

One possible solution can be the following:

```js
function something(userInput){
  let m = moment(userInput, [moment.ISO_8601, 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ]);
  if( !m.isValid() ){
    // throw "Invalid input";
  }
  return m.locale('fr').format('LL');
}

['2/3/1986', 'aaa', '10-15-2017'].forEach((userInput) => {
  console.log( something(userInput) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/fr.js"></script>
```