# How do I find what moment() constructor throws a deprecation error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, momentjs

In a handful of places, I use `moment.js` to take various inputs and turn them into a moment object.

In some places I get the

> "Moment Constructor Falls back to JS Date..."

warning that has been mentioned here so many times. I understand the problem, and the solution, but my question is how to identify *which* instance of the `moment()` usage is the problem.

Is there any reasonable way to track which instance is the problematic one?

**Note:** It's also possible that one of the JS libraries that I'm using is calling `moment()` in the problematic way - it's not necessarily in my code directly.

Comment: what about debugger and breakpoints?

Comment: You can't really tell just from what the code looks like. Any call to `moment()` with a single string argument *might* result in the warning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs

Answer (score 3):

Add a hook:

```
moment.deprecationHandler = () => {debugger}
```

Or upgrade the warning to an error:

```
moment.deprecationHandler = (_,msg) => {throw new Error(msg)}
```

This seems to be somewhat undocumented. How to find this out? I see a stack trace in Chrome when I trip the warning:

```
> moment('20 Dec 2018')
global.js:293 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized […]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback (https://momentjs.com/static/js/global.js:320:98)
[…]
```

See what's inside that function:

```
> moment.createFromInputFallback
ƒ () {
        if (hooks.deprecationHandler != null) {
            hooks.deprecationHandler(null, msg);
        }
        if (firstTime) {
            var args = [];
           …
> moment.deprecationHandler
null
```