# Using Moment.js, check if date string is valid without deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Before this is marked as a duplicate out of hand--for there are a dozen questions that ask *how* to check the validity of a date string using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)--I *am* asking a question that is different, at least from the first dozen or so results I found.  [how to handle deprecation warning in momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101278/how-to-handle-deprecation-warning-in-momentjs) does *not* answer my question, as using `moment(str, moment.ISO_8601)` would only parse a single format.

I'm writing a helper function `add(start, ...durations)` which adds each of the durations to start and returns the resulting object.  I want `start` to be a `moment`, a `duration`, or a string or object that can be parsed as one of those.  If `start` is a moment or can be parsed as a `moment`, `add` will return a `moment` object; if it is a `duration` or can be parsed as a `duration`, `add` will return a `duration`; else `add` will return `moment.invalid()`.

```js
/* prep... ignore */
console.config({ maximize: true, timeStamps: false, autoScroll: false });

/* important code */
function tryParse(value) {
  let val = moment(value);
  if (val.isValid()) {
    return val;
  }

  val = moment.duration(value);
  // known issue: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1805
  // duration.isValid() always true for a string, regardless of validity
  // this is the hacky workaround
  if (val.toISOString() !== 'P0D') {
    return val;
  }
  
  return moment.invalid();
}

function add(start, ...durations) {
  if (!(start instanceof moment || moment.isDuration(start))) {
    start = tryParse(start);
  }
  
  if (!start.isValid || !start.isValid()) {
    return moment.invalid();
  }
  
  return durations.reduce((val, duration) => val.add(duration), start);
}

const testCases = [
  ["moment('2020-07-04')",        'moment',   true],
  ["moment.duration(1, 'hour')",  'duration', true],
  ["'2020-07-04'",                'moment',   true],
  ["'6:30:00'",                   'duration', true],
  ["[2020, 7, 4, 13, 48]",        'moment',   true],
  ["'abcd'",                      'invalid',  false],
  ["NaN",                         'invalid',  false],
  ["moment.invalid()",            'invalid',  false],
];

const results = testCases.reduce((results, [exp, expectedType, expectedValidity]) => {
  const start = eval(exp);
  const sum = add(start, '1:00'); // adds one hour
  const isValid = sum.isValid();
  const type = 
    !isValid ? 'invalid' :
    sum instanceof moment ? 'moment' :
    'duration';
    
  return {
    ...results,
    [exp]: {
      expectedType,
      type,
      expectedValidity,
      isValid,
      success: expectedValidity === isValid && type === expectedType,
    }
  };
}, {});

console.table(results);

/* more table formatting */
document.querySelector('.as-console-table thead th').innerText = 'expression';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

My code works, but it gives an ugly warning the first time a duration string is passed into `moment()` inside `tryParse()`.  Since my function assumes the string may be invalid, the warning should be ignored--I don't want it generated at all.  This wouldn't be an issue if I were running this code in the browser since users would never see the warning, but I'm running this in a node environment.

I suppose I could do something nasty like:

```js
function tryParse(value) {
  const warn = console.warn;
  console.warn = () => {};
  try {
    // ...
  } finally {
    console.warn = warn;
  }
```

This seems like a horrible practice, though.

Comment: @falinsky No.  That would only support a single date format.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23263380/1470607), see namely [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46410816/1470607).

Comment: @Nit so it is.  Thank you!